# Understanding http request data transfer - nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, https

I have been reading through some node docs and am curious as to how the request headers/body/data get sent over.

On nodejs's docs, they show sample code to parse the body. So the data is streamed over and you react by pushing each chunk to a string which you can then parse.

Why wouldn't the same thing be happening on the headers? Instead you can just directly receive them. Can anyone explain why this is or have a source that explain how this data is sent/received generally?

**Method, URL and Headers**

```
 var headers = request.headers;
 var userAgent = headers['user-agent'];
```

**Request Body**

```
var body = [];
request.on('data', function(chunk) {
  body.push(chunk);
}).on('end', function() {
  body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
  // at this point, `body` has the entire request body stored in it as a string
});
```

Source: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/